# Is there a way to automate Os built in Color Picker?

Tags: macos, puppeteer, color-picker

We use Puppeteer to Automate our tests. Our application uses OS built-in Color Picker for certain color combos.
I am unable to figure out a way to automate this. Can anyone please help and guide?

- Is there an api for the OS default Color panel - picker?
- I cannot inspect or act on the elements of this color panel. How can I proceed? Please suggest.

Thank you

Comment: This is an interesting question. Obviously with Puppeteer you control the browser, and using the OS colour picker doesn't allow you to perform any action on it. That's it. 

The only thing I can think of would be mock the outcome of using the OS colour picker. Perhaps you could skip the need of interact with it altogether and just fake the result in the DOM instead.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I think I am going to do as you said.. as my main focus is on setting the colour and not interacting with the colour panel.